# Переход на другую страницу по соответствию, через JS

Tags: javascript

учусь пока, мне нужно сделать вот так.
Имеется что-то вроде формы входа, нужно чтобы при вводе определенного слова и нажатии кнопки, меня отправляло на с /index.html на /info.html, а если слово введенно неправильно, то чтобы вышло окошко с ошибкой. Как это сделать?

Comment: А что уже имеется? А какие знания по js уже есть у вас? На какой уровень рассчитывать?

Comment: Самые самые, нулевые, чисто переменные могу поменять, поэтому и проблема(

Comment: Тогда вам надо книгу для новичков для начала почитать.

Comment: Спасибо, в скором времени))

Answer (score 1):

Это вообще ни в коем случае нельзя использовать на страницах входа или еще где-либо. Просто для изучений, для общей инфы. Максимально не безопасный код, т.к. правильный пароль может увидеть любой желающий в исходном коде сайта.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('loginButton');
const input = document.getElementById('login');
const correctLogin = 'admin';

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (input.value === correctLogin) {
    window.location.href = '/info.html';
  }
  else {
    alert('login incorrect!');
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="login" placeholder="Введите логин">
<button id="loginButton">Тык</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я просто для ознакомления конечно же.